# Insert image in Mysql database by using c# in vs

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How to insert an image in Mysql database by using c# in visual studio 2012 ?
I used this code,but there is something wrong with it and I don't know what is it ?
Also, what should I put inside the parentheses in this code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(); to save the value as an image.
public partial class Invoices : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; userid=root; password=""; database=admindb; allowuservariables=True");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tablename(invoicesfp) VALUES (@val1)";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("val1");
    connection.Open();
    cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    #region fileupload
    string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string ret = ChangeName();
    string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Invoices") + "\\" + ret;

    try
    {
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is ArgumentNullException || ex is NullReferenceException)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    string PicAddress = "~/Invoices/" + ret;

    #endregion
 }

   public static string ChangeName()
  {
    return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".jpg";
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to save the image, i.e. the binary data to the database. Or are you trying to save just an address to the image on the webserver?

Comment: I wanted to save the image itself but someone told me that is better to save the address to take less space. What do u think?. And, I need the images to be in a category on the website to facilitate the access to them.

Comment: What is the problem? Image is not being stored? Do you get error messages? What?

Comment: I got the error message in this code : cmd.Parameters.Add("val1"); . Should I put another thing instead of that inside the parentheses?.